# SELECT JOIN with PDO across two seperate databases

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, pdo

I am working on a migration plugin to move data from a database for OSCommerce to a WooCommerce (Wordpress) database. For most of my queries I can select from the OSCommerce database and insert into the WP database without any issue. There's one query, however, that seems to require a JOIN on tables from each database. I can't seem to figure out if this is possible after a few google searches so here I am. Here's what I have:

```
$os_connect = new PDO($os_connect_string, $os_username, $os_password);
$wp_connect = new PDO($wp_connect_string, $wp_username, $wp_password);

$os_statement = $os_connect->prepare("
    SELECT  categories_id+15
    FROM    categories
");

$os_statement->execute();
$os_result = $os_statement->fetchAll();

$wp_select = $wp_connect->prepare("
    SELECT  ID
    FROM    wp_posts
    WHERE   post_type = 'attachment'
    AND     post_parent = 0
");
$wp_select->execute();
$wp_result = $wp_select->fetchAll();

// INSERT data from both of the selects below
```

The problem with this method is that I am getting the two things I need but not in the correct order like I should be. The query I need to use is:

```
INSERT INTO `redhillcutlery.com.mm-dev.net`.wp_woocommerce_termmeta(woocommerce_term_id, meta_key, meta_value)
    SELECT   os.categories_id+15, 'thumbnail_id', wp.ID
    FROM     `redhill_oscommerce`.categories AS os
    JOIN     `redhillcutlery.com.mm-dev.net`.wp_posts AS wp
    ON       os.categories_image = wp.post_title
    WHERE    wp.post_type = 'attachment'
    AND      wp.post_parent = 0
```

This query works correctly because of the `ON os.categories_image = wp.post_title` section makes sure the right images make it to the right category instead of the way my PDO statements just give them to me in order and end up giving me the wrong images. So any ideas how I can make this `JOIN` statement work?

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question but I put `ORDER BY` on both of my `SELECT` statements which resulted in the images coming through in the right order. I would still prefer to join the two tables to force the images to match rather than relying on the `ORDER BY` to pull the correct images.

Comment: What is the commonality in the columns that you're joining on?

Comment: previous to this statement I pull all the category image names into the wp_posts table and make the post_title be the categories_image string. So if I join on the image string and the post_title being equal then I will confirm that the woocommerce_term_id is pointing to the correct post.

I believe this answers your question but I could be wrong...

Comment: @JayBlanchard I meant to tag you in my previous comment and for some reason I can't edit it...

Comment: Yes, that answers the question. Your query should work, are you getting an error?

Comment: @JayBlanchard The query works just fine if I'm doing it from phpmyadmin but I have no idea how to link the two databases together with PDO's. Since the two databases are part of different PDO classes.

Comment: You cannot do it with two connections. You have to have a connection that works for both databases.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I was afraid of that... there's no way to connect both databases in one PDO as far as I know since they're on different servers...

Comment: Yep, the further they get away from each other the worse it becomes.